# $rootscope throwing error in angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm practicing `$rootscope` in Angular JS. Here I'm defining `rootscope` as below

```
var sample=angular.module("sample",[]).run(['$rootscope', function($rootScope){
            $rootScope.months=12;
        }])
```

And this rootscope calling in inner scope as below

```
sample.controller('salary', ['$scope','$rootscope', function($rootScope,$scope){
            $scope.dept="developer";
            $scope.salary=58900
            $scope.getAnualSalary=function () {
                return (this.salary)*$rootScope.months;
            }
        }])
```

but I doesn't showing desired result and throwing error in console

> angular.js:14800 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/unpr?p0=%24rootscopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24rootscope%20%3C-%20salary

[full code is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/HHAGbxJBE5ljtzWJscZy?p=preview)

what's the wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

change the order. You need to have the same order in both arguments and string values

```
sample.controller('salary', ['$scope','$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope){
```

Comment: did u change the rootscope to rootScope

Comment: inside your method you might want to return scope.salary. `return ($scope.salary)*$rootScope.months;`

Comment: I didn't think angular js is case sensitive, I change it is working fine. Thanks for corrections

Answer (score 1):

Correct injector is **$rootScope** (case sensitive)

```
var sample=angular.module("sample",[]).run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
```

Also the order should be same in strings and function arguments

```
sample.controller('salary', ['$scope','$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope){
```